# Finding roots but not asymptotes of a function

Tags: c++, math

I writing a program to numerically find the roots of functions with irrational roots by various methods.
For methods such as linear interpolation, you need to find the approximate range in which a root lies, for this I wrote this code:

```
bool fxn1 = false;
bool fxn2 = false;
vector<float> root_list;

if(f_x(-100) < 0)
{
    fxn2 = true;
}
for(float i = -99.99; i < 100.01; i += 0.01)
{

    fxn1 = fxn2;
    if(f_x(i) < 0)
    {
        fxn2 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        fxn2 = false;
    }
    if((fxn1 == false && fxn2 == true) || (fxn1 == true && fxn2 == false))
    {
        root_list.push_back(i-0.01);
        root_list.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

However, for non-continuous functions (i.e. functions with asymptotes), this code will also be triggered when the function swaps from positive to negative values either side of the asymptote.
Is there a way to get the program to tell the difference between a root and an asymptote?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not really a programming problem but a math problem. But an asymptote has the property that it runs off to infinity, so if `f_x(i) < 0` then you should have `f_x(i + 0.005) < f_x(i)` and otherwise `f_x(i - 0.005) > f_x(i)`.

Comment: Also note that  you can replace both `if`- statements by the shorter `fxn2 = f_x(i) < 0; if( fxn1 != fxn2 ) { ... }`, replacing 9 lines by 2.

Comment: Instead of the signs, just look at the absolute value and see if it is small enough.

Comment: Third note: this method will not find zeroes of e.g. `f(x) = |x|` which have the same signs on both sides of the root.

Comment: You don't need tolerance/epsilon values when the root finder is bracketed. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function, `f(x)`, is converging on a point inside `[a,b]` then the half-way point `(a + b) / 2` should be closer to zero than `a` or `b`.

This observation leads to the following procedure:

```
Let mid = (a + b) / 2
If |f(mid)| < |f(a)| AND |f(mid)| < |f(b)| Then
   Algorithm has converged to a root
Else
   Algorithm has converged to an asymptote
End
```

In this pseudo code `|.|` denotes floating-point absolute value.

Comment: Be careful, in the case of `1/x` and a symmetric interval, `f(mid)` may not exist. Be prepared to handle "division by zero" errors.

Comment: You make a good point, although it is not uncommon for a root finder to operate on the function as a black box. I would suggest throwing an exception if the function is undefined at a point and handling it appropriately.

Comment: *If the function, f(x), is converging on a point inside [a,b] then the half-way point (a + b) / 2 should be closer to zero than a or b*. That's wrong. It is only true for *nice* functions but you can easily find counterexamples with a function as simple as f(x) = x sin(1/x) for x # 0 and f(0) = 0. I can guarantee you that is is continuous on 0 but that your property is wrong on it.

Answer (score 0):

Finding numerically a root only make sense if the function has *nice* properties, and at least is continuous. What would you think about this one:

f: x -> f(x) defined by:

- 2 * i < x < 2 * i + 1 (i element of Z) : f(x) = x
- 2 - i + 1 < x < 2 * i (i element of Z) : f(x) = -x
- x = i (i element of Z) : f(x) = 1

It is perfectly defined on R, is bounded on any bounded interval, has positive and negative values on any interval of size > 1, and is continuous on any non integer point, but it has no root.

It is simply because the rule that a root must exist on segment ]x, y[ if x < 0 < y or y < 0 < x only applies if the function is continuous on the interval.

And good luck if you want to numerically test for continuity of a function...